# Install DBeaver SQLite driver offline?

Tags: sqlite, dbeaver

I'd like to use DBeaver with SQLite, but the network firewall disallows external connections. So DBeaver cannot download the driver automatically.

Where can I download the SQLite driver for it and how can I install it manually in DBeaver?

Answer (score 4):

DBeaver [supports](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio-10/zend-studio.htm#create_manage_database_with_dbeaver.htm) any database that has a JDBC driver. So, the best thing to do is to go to the SQLite people themselves - they have a list of such drivers [here](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers). The page itself is quite old, so don't worry about the dates - just check around and see which one best suits your needs/is supported. Just as a matter of interest, SQuirreL SQL also works via JDBC - it's pure Java and is, IHMO, more mature than DBeaver, but YMMV.

Comment: Can SQuirrel SQL cancel long queries that I executed? Or is JDBC limited in any way?

Comment: Check [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/squirrel-sql/bugs/960/). It's a bug report - but there's a response by someone else saying that it works for them. My suggestion is that you download it and see does it meet your needs - see does it cancel your problem queries. I have used both in the past (discovered DBeaver before SQuirreL) and IMHO, SQuirreL is superior - but you are, of course, free to make up your own mind :-). It was just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile I found where to get the drivers for offline installation:
http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/files/
It seems this link is hidden.

Comment: Browsing the JDBC subfolder is forbidden so this is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of DBeaver wants to contact xerial.org for downloading the driver. This site leads to the project's github page, where you can also download the driver: https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc